# why is Django giving me a 404 error

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

I am currently trying to complete the Django 2.0 tutorial Poll application.  I am using Django version 2.0.7 and Python 3.7.0.  I have set up a virtual environment for this project.  I am very new to Django so apologies if my terminology is incorrect.

Basically, I cant get part 1 to work.

I have tried numerous times to run it and I cant seem to figure out why it wont work.

Before I create the Polls app the site runs correctly and I get the rocket ship, however after I create the app, update polls/views.py, create the polls/urls.py file and update the mysite/urls.py, I get the following error:

Page not found (404)
Request method GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. polls/
2. admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

I thought my code was incorrect, so I copied and pasted the code from the website directly and tried to run it.  It still wont work.

Below is the code I am trying and the directory layout.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure I am just missing something simple.

Thank you.

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), ]
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Directory of C:\Users\ad\Documents\projects\mysite\msenv\mysite\mysite

print.txt

settings.py

urls.py

wsgi.py

**init**.py

**pycache**

Directory of C:\Users\ad\Documents\projects\mysite\msenv\mysite\polls

admin.py

apps.py

migrations

models.py

tests.py

urls.py

views.py

**init**.py

**pycache**

Comment: once you add an app and redirect it, you have to call it using the url pattern you used in the app. so, for you try http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. You should read the error message: it's telling you that you are going to /, which you haven't defined, rather than /polls or /admin, which you have.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm really annoyed at myself for missing that.  It says it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you added your app name inside settings.py make sure you have added the name in settings.py which resides under project folder

in your case it will be here:

> Directory of C:\Users\ad\Documents\projects\mysite\msenv\mysite\mysite

like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app_name',] # <--- polls in your case
```

make sure you are using your routes you have defined to access the correct page

for example in your case:

your website's routes are:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and your application 'polls' routes are:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), 
]
```

according to your views.py file

which is this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

you must visit http://localhost:{port number}/polls/ or http://127.0.0.1:{port number}/polls/

default port number is 8000

after running server using python manage.py runserver

to get your page as an output on browser

Comment: Thanks for your help, annoyed I missed adding polls to the end of the address.