# Django urls and views properly defined, still showing 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a blog which was running without any error. Different users can register, login, and post articles. Users can write/edit/delete comments on the articles. Previously, the URL of the articles were decided using 'article id'. Later, I read [this](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/generating-slugs-automatically-in-django-easy-solid-approaches/) tutorial and added slug along with id in the URL for every article's Detail View. Then I deleted my old articles since they didn't have any slugs.

After this change, a user can create a comment successfully, but cannot 'edit' or 'delete' any comment. Whenever 'edit' or 'delete' button is pressed, 404 error is shown.
[See the error image by pressing this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BELt.png).

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/articles/33/comment_edit/
>
> Raised by: articles.views.ArticleDetailView
>
> No article found matching the query

My corresponding files are listed below:

**urls.py** (inside Articles App directory)

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (ArticleListView, ArticleUpdateView, ArticleDetailView, ArticleDeleteView, ArticleCreateView, 
                    CommentCreateView, CommentUpdateView, CommentDeleteView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/edit/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/delete/', ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name='article_delete'),
    path('new/', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article_new'),
    #Comments below
    path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_new'),
    path('<int:pk>/comment_edit/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/comment_delete/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_delete'),
]
```

I have tried and run the website by commenting out the url for comments, i.e., the last three lines above. The error shown is the same. This is strange.

**urls.py** (inside Project directory)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
]
```

**views.py** (inside Articles App directory)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Article, Comment

# Create your views here.
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    ordering = ['-date']

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    query_pk_and_slug = True

class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ('title', 'body',)
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    #def test_func for UserPassesTestMixin
    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user
    success_message = 'Article was updated successfully!'        

class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'
    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user
    success_message = 'Article was deleted successfully!'

class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ('title', 'body')  
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    login_url = 'login' #for LoginRequiredMixin, overriding default login url at accounts/login
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    success_message = 'Article was created successfully!'    

#Now for the feature of adding comments on listview and detailview of articles
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    query_pk_and_slug = True
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.article = Article.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
    success_message = 'Comment was posted successfully!'    

class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'comment_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    #def test_func for UserPassesTestMixin
    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user
    success_message = 'Comment was updated successfully!'


class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
    login_url = 'login'
    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user
    success_message = 'Comment was deleted successfully!'
```

**models.py** (inside Articles App directory)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        default='',
        editable=False,
        max_length=255,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'pk': self.id,
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse("article_detail", kwargs=kwargs)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.title
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'pk': self.article.id,
            'slug': self.article.slug
        }
        return reverse("article_detail", kwargs=kwargs)
```

The links for creating a comment, editing a comment, and deleting a comment in any **html** file looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'comment_new' article.pk article.slug %}">Add Comment</a>
<a href="{% url 'comment_edit' comment.pk %}">Edit Comment</a>
<a href="{% url 'comment_delete' comment.pk %}">Delete Comment</a>
```

In my **settings.py** file, `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`.

Kindly help me with this problem. I have searched online but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the error message is

```
Raised by: articles.views.ArticleDetailView
```

You are trying to edit a comment at `/articles/33/comment_edit/`, but it is matching the URL pattern:

```
path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
```

This gives a 404, because you don't have an article with pk=33 and slug='comment_edit'.

You could fix the issue by moving the `CommentUpdateView` above `ArticleDetailView` so that it matches first.

Comment: I have done what you have said. I moved the URLs for the comment to the top. Now, the comment can be edited smoothly. But now, when I am trying to delete a comment, this error is shown, `NoReverseMatch at /articles/28/comment_delete/
Reverse for 'article_detail' with arguments '(18,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']`

Comment: That's on a different URL, `/articles/28/comment_delete/`. Look at the error `with arguments '(18,)'` - you have provided the primary key but not the slug. If you still need help, please ask a new question because it's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your app name inside `settings.py`? Make sure you have added the name in settings.py which resides under the project folder.

Like so,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app_name',] # <--- WhatEver is called
```

And also make sure you are using your routes you have defined to access the correct page

Comment: Yes, I have properly defined the installed apps in settings.py file. In the case of Articles app, I have used `'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'`, and same for other apps.

Comment: That sounds right. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347762/6505847 and see if this helps